# Page Creation role in Sitecore Habitat

Tags: security, habitat, role-management

In the Sitecore Habitat implementation, I am looking for a role that is allowed to create/rename and delete items. I see the role `habitat\Project Habitat Content Author`, that is only allowed to read and write.

[image]

For the rest, I only see feature roles, that can only edit fields. So, which role is supposed to create/rename and delete items in the content tree?

Comment: Might be able to provide a better answer if you clarify what you're looking for / what you're trying to accomplish. Security configuration tends to be very specific to the organization/project.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a quick examination, I'd say the the security configuration within Habitat is incomplete and not a good reference. In your own implementation, your primary content author role should certainly be granted those additional permissions.